# Making regular expressions bold

Tags: php, regex

I have some coordinates on my site that are printed as:

```
z:000
```

I would like to have this (including the z) printed in bold.
The coordinates are in a text string like so:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum z:000 dolor sit amet';
```

I think I have to do this with Regex, but I'm not getting it to work.
The first part is fixed, so the parts of the regex are `^z:` and `[0-9]`

Comment: If you are trying to do this with a regex, you should include it in your question so that folks have all the information at hand to be able to offer you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help

```
preg_replace("/(z:[0-9]{3})/", '<b>${1}</b>', $string);
```

Works for z:000 to z:999

Comment: Sure, that worked :) Thanks! I'll mark it as soon as the 5 minute counter is over ;)

Comment: I replaced the `3` with `1,` so it can do any number ;)

Comment: For all numbers, you can replace `{3}` or `{1,}` by a single star `*` which means "0 or more" or a plus `+` which means "1 or more".

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace("/z:[0-9][0-9][0-9]/", "<b>\\0</b>", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with some basic CSS:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum <span class="mark">z:000</span> dolor sit amet';
```

In the header, you will have something like this

```
<style type="text/css">
.mark{font-weight:bold;}
</style>
```

Comment: That doesn't allow for variable input, since the string is taken from a database ;) thanks anyway

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Then the solution below will work quite fine.
You can use CSS anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need regex, just need HTML formatting!

Encase your string in HTML bold tags:

```
$string = '<b>Lorem ipsum z:000 dolor sit amet</b>';
```

Comment: The OP only wants *part* of the output to be formatted in bold.

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear enough, I meant only the z:000, thanks anyway.. I'll edit my post ;)

Comment: ah sorry! In that case yes you need regex unless you store the z value in a variable and encase it in <b></b>